# Problem building dictionary from series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column CAS_BRM_IDA of type category (even if its values seem of foat type ... but they are not meaningful per se)

I built the following serie from that dataframe :

```
p = df.groupby( [ 'CAS_BRM_IDA' ] ).mean()[ 'TOP_FRD']
print( p )
```

Result displayed :

```
CAS_BRM_IDA
10.0       0.001131
13.0       0.000000
15.0       0.002038
17.0       0.000000
20.0       0.003802
...
missing    0.019549
```

I then tried to build a dictionary using that serie :

```
mydic = dict( [ ( i , p[i] ) for i in p.index ] )
```

But I got the following error message :

> ```
> TypeError: cannot do label indexing on
>   <class 'pandas.core.indexes.category.CategoricalIndex'>
>    with these indexers [10.0] of <class 'float'>
> ```

Some details about the p index :

```
CategoricalIndex(
    [10.0, 13.0, 15.0, 17.0, 20.0, 21.0, 30.0, 31.0, 40.0, 43.0,
     50.0, 51.0, 56.0, 'missing'],
     categories=[10.0, 13.0, 15.0, 17.0, 20.0, 21.0, 30.0, 31.0, ...],
     ordered=False, name='CAS_BRM_IDA', dtype='category')
```

I can't figure out where is the problem.  '10.0' value seems to have been interpreted as float which I thought it's not.

How can I build a dict from a Series with a Categorical Index which contains floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the intrinsic pandas conversion:

```
p.to_dict()
```

Comment: It worked just fine. I did not know that syntax. Thanks.